# Service injection in angularjs directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

I'm try to inject service to directive, and it's throwing error

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <-
>   AppService <- scoreDirective

this is my Directive

```
angular.module('MyApp.directives').directive('score', ['$compile', 'AppService', function($compile, AppService) {
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      scope: {},
      templateUrl: 'dashboard/score.html',
      controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {

      }],
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller, firebase) {
         // some code here
        }
      }
}]);
```

And this is Service

```
'use strict';

angular.module('MyApp.services').service('AppService', function($scope, $firebase, FIREBASE_ROOT) {

       // some code here

});
```

Wat I am doing wrong?

Comment: There's nothing like $scope when it comes to services. Remove the injection of $scope inside your Service Declaration.

Comment: You can't inject scope into services. It just doesn't make any sense, because Services are application layer that can span multiple controllers, directives.

Comment: Well, as said in the duplicate question, one can use `$rootScope` as a dependency of a service. It's not recommended though.